# ServiceStack as Windows Service with Razor - Setup Project

Tags: razor, windows-services, servicestack, setup-project

I have a servicestack project using razor exposed through a windows service, and need to create a setup project to install it (as opposed to the batch files in the demo's I've seen).

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this with a packaged setup project? Looking at the folder where the windows service files were installed, it only has the dll's, not the razor views... so I coped those over, and now I see this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting that error, can you double-check that you're deploying the **orignal** Razor source files and not some interim build.

Otherwise some other options for hosting Razor is to change them to **Embedded Resources**, that way the original Source files get compiled into your .dll so you don't need to deploy them to your project.

Or you can [pre-compile Razor Views](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Compiled-Razor-Views) that way the implementation is compiled into the .dll.

Comment: Pre-compiled worked. I think the issue was related to either my projects having "ServiceStack" in the name (messing with the razor views compiled code) or running the windows service under a specific domain user (not local system)